# Converter soma de minutos em formato de horas (ex: 70min = 01:10) com jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, soma

Tenho o seguinte script que pega as horas e minutos de cada dia da semana, onde as variáveis que começam com `m` são os **minutos** de cada dia da semana (vindo de um select) e as que começam com `h` são das **horas**.

Eu estou pegando os valores de horas, multiplicando por 60 para ter os minutos e somando com todos os minutos e tenho no final, a somatório em minutos.

Como faço para converter esses minutos em horas?

Ex: 70minutos resultaria 01:10

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").change(function(){
      //VARIAVEIS MINUTOS
      var mseg = parseInt($("#mseg").val());
      var mter = parseInt($("#mter").val());
      var mqua = parseInt($("#mqua").val());
      var mqui = parseInt($("#mqui").val());
      var msex = parseInt($("#msex").val());
      var msab = parseInt($("#msab").val());
      var mdom = parseInt($("#mdom").val());
      var totalminutos = mseg + mter + mqua + mqui + msex + msab + mdom;
      //VARIAVEIS HORAS
      var hseg = parseInt($("#hseg").val());
      var hter = parseInt($("#hter").val());
      var hqua = parseInt($("#hqua").val());
      var hqui = parseInt($("#hqui").val());
      var hsex = parseInt($("#hsex").val());
      var hsab = parseInt($("#hsab").val());
      var hdom = parseInt($("#hdom").val());
      var totalhoras = (hseg + hter + hqua + hqui + hsex + hsab + hdom) * 60;
      var total = (totalhoras + totalminutos);
      $("#total").val(total);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode criar uma função que receberá o valor em minutos, utilizará a função `Math.floor` para remover a parte inteira e um `mod` (operador `%`) para obter o resto da divisão por 60:

```js
const converter = (minutos) => {
  const horas = Math.floor(minutos/ 60);          
  const min = minutos % 60;
  const textoHoras = (`00${horas}`).slice(-2);
  const textoMinutos = (`00${min}`).slice(-2);
  
  return `${textoHoras }:${textoMinutos}`;
};

console.log(converter(70));
```

Comment: deu, mas não deu...rs, Alterei a parte do console.log para trazer o resultado: var total = converter(total); $("#total").val(total);. Ele calcula, mas dá um erro: jquery.min.js:2 The specified value "0:10" is not a valid number. The value must match to the following regular expression: -?(\d+|\d+\.\d+|\.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?

Comment: @LeandroMarzullo o input no qual você vai colocar o resultado é number?

Comment: puts, era isso mesmo...rs, alterei para texto e foi normal, só mais um detalhezinho, tem como arredondar 2 casa? ex: 0:2 ser 0:02 ou isso vai com máscara

Comment: @LeandroMarzullo adicionado

Comment: Perfeito, funcionou certinho, valeu!